# SwiftUI Menu main "Button" view with changing text

Tags: button, swiftui, view, menu

I am using a menu and the view I have for the main button has text inside it which can change. It's between 4 and 6 characters.

When the text changes, the button animates left and right and the text animates in (which is not what I want) ..
I'd ideally like to use a buttonStyle but this doesn't seem possible.

Any ideas how I can keep the button static ? The right button is a "real" button which behaves.

[image]

```
Menu {
                            
                            if fuelTypeisAvailable(fuelType: "Gazole") {
                                
                                Button {
                                    updateStuff()
                                    Haptics.shared.play(.light)
                                    preferredFuelType = "Gazole"
                                    
                                } label: {
                                    Label("Gazole       €\(closestGazole ?? "")", systemImage: isPreferedFuelType(type: "Gazole"))
                                    
                                   
                                }
                            }

etc




label: {

                            // This is the left blue button

                            Text("\(preferredFuelType)")
                            .padding(25)
                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .light, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                .background(
                                   Circle()
                                    .fill(.blue).opacity(leftButtonIsHidden ? 0 : 0.8)

                                 )
```

}

Comment: you could try to add `.animation(nil, value: preferredFuelType)` to your `Text`. But it´s hard to tell without an [mre]. E.g. how are you changing `preferredFuelType`?

Comment: I'll give it a go thanks. preferredFuelType is set as : @AppStorage("preferredFuelType") private var preferredFuelType: String  = "SP98" and it's simply updated with preferredFuelType = "Whatever"

Comment: This didn't change anything unfortunately. I placed it under the Text line. Thanks

Comment: Then please try to post a [mre]. I don´t think anyone can help here without more info.

Comment: Got it thank you. I have managed to progress on it and you were right about the animation part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version that fixes the animation issues. It even accepts the buttonStyle.

```
label: {
                            
            // This is the left blue button
            ZStack{
            Circle().fill(.blue).opacity(0.8)
                                
           Text("\(preferredFuelType)")
           .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .light, design: .default))
           .foregroundColor(.primary)
           .animation(nil)
                }.frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                  }
             .buttonStyle(TwitterButtonStyle())
```